# Trying to rename recorded file with a method

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-mediarecorder

I'm trying to rename files that I recorded with MediaRecorder. This is how I approched this.

First, I created a startRecording() and stopRecording method

```
public void startRecording (){
     recorder = new MediaRecorder();
     recorder.reset();      
     recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
     recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
     recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
     if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
     {
         externalStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
         externalOutputPath = externalStoragePath + File.separator + "/Android/data/com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad/test.mp3";
         recorder.setOutputFile(externalOutputPath);
     }
     else
     {
        storagePath = Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        recorder.setOutputFile(storagePath + "/Android/data/com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad/test.mp3");
     }
     recorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
     recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);

     try {
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void stopRecording() {
    if (null != recorder) {
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.reset();
        recorder.release();

        recorder = null;
    }
}
```

This is how I start and stop recording:

```
recBtn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                recBtn.setImageResource(com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad.R.drawable.record_btn_pressed);
                startRecording();
            }
            else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            {
                recBtn.setImageResource(com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad.R.drawable.record_btn);
                stopRecording();
                nameAlert();
            }
            return true;
        }

    });
} //END OF ONCREATE
```

So the next thing I wanted to do is to be able to set the name of the output file each time I stop pressing the record button. I tried to do it by creating a new method that would be called each time I stop recording.

```
public void nameAlert() {
    final EditText etFileName = (EditText) findViewById(com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad.R.id.etFileName);
    Button okBtn = (Button) findViewById(com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad.R.id.okBtn);

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog (getApplicationContext(), android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad.R.layout.alert_name);

    okBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fileName = etFileName.getText().toString();
            recorder.setOutputFile(externalStoragePath + File.separator + "/Android/data/com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad/" + fileName + ".mp3");
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

I then added this method right after I called stopRecording();

Now everytime I stop recording (by stop touching the imagebutton) the app crashes. This is the logcat file:

```
08-01 22:39:26.790: E/InputEventReceiver(8258): Exception dispatching input event.
08-01 22:39:26.790: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8258): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
08-01 22:39:26.806: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8258): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-01 22:39:26.806: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8258):   at com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad.MainActivity.nameAlert(MainActivity.java:117)
08-01 22:39:26.806: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8258):   at com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad.MainActivity$3.onTouch(MainActivity.java:59)
08-01 22:39:26.822: E/AndroidRuntime(8258): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 22:39:26.822: E/AndroidRuntime(8258): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-01 22:39:26.822: E/AndroidRuntime(8258):     at com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad.MainActivity.nameAlert(MainActivity.java:117)
08-01 22:39:26.822: E/AndroidRuntime(8258):     at com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad.MainActivity$3.onTouch(MainActivity.java:59)
```

It says the error is on line 117 and 59.

Line 59:

```
nameAlert();
```

Line 117:

```
okBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

I'm still a beginner programmer so maybe I approached this the wrong way, my thinking as a programmer isn't yet perfect, so please let me know how I could do this. Thank you!

Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/dim"
android:padding="30dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="129dp"
    android:text="Enter the name of the recorded file:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etFileName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/okBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etFileName"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Ok" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Show your layout file. The problem is that okBtn is null, meaning that it did not find any view with the id `okBtn` (as in `com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad.R.id.okBtn`) in the current activity.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Edited my original post, please check it. Could the problem also be the fact that I'm using tablayout?

Comment: In your layout file you have a `<requestFocus />`-tag. Should that one really be there? Doesn't Eclipse say that there are some errors in your XML ?

Comment: I see no TableLayout, only a RelativeLayout and the RelativeLayout should not be the problem.

Comment: @MatejJohnson : Why are you fully qualifying your resources with `com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad`? You should only need to use `R.id...` and `R.layout...`

Comment: @Squonk it wants me to, if I try to do it by R.id or R.layout it underlines it with red, I have no idea why, it never happened before

Comment: @MatejJohnson : Check your `imports`. Are you importing `android.R` or any other `R` class? If so, delete those imports, get rid of the fully qualified `R` references (but keep the `android.R` references as fully qualified) and clean your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you really need a specific design for your app, why don't you try using a simple dialog builder? You can add edittext and a button to your dialog programatically and it'll work aswell. Something like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Your message");
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
builder.setView(input);
```

Then just set your positive and negative button and you're good.

Comment: Thanks, I did this for now and it works. I'll still need to edit the layout in the future so this won't be permanent but for testing purposes it's great